# gwt plugin for chrome

Tags: gwt, google-chrome

I am developing GWT application. In dev mode, I can successfully open the app in FF and IE. However, when I try to open it in chrome, I get the missing plugin window. After I click on it, it downloads the .crx which I use to install (I get the successfully installed dialog) However, when I refresh the browser, I get the same result. Anybody faced a similar situation? Any workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anyone having the problem with the gwt-chrome plug-in(that it prompting to install the plugin),download http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582  and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the GWT toolbox in the omnibox? (address bar)

Have a look here for more troubleshooting tips: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM

Comment: when i am installed the plugin it was showing the omnibox after refresh the browser same result and in the tools.extensions gwtplugin is enabled too.

Comment: i installed the dlls now it was not prompting me to install the plugin again,but i am not able to connect to the development mode it throws an error "Plug in failed to connect to the server at"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have plugins disabled? chrome://chrome/settings/content

What do you see on the plugins page? chrome://plugins/ You should be looking for "GWT DevMode Plugin - Version: 1.0"

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you set your Chrome privacy settings regarding plugins to anything other than "Run automatically". You can access these settings in Settings -> Privacy -> Content settings... -> Plug-ins. I had mine set to "Click to play" and was getting the exact same behaviour.