# Google chrome plugin not working with chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt

I have developed a website using google web toolkit and the web site works fine on firefox.However,in google chrome the plugin is not working with Google chrome.My current version of google chrome is 22. It was initially giving this error

[image]

I have added the google chrome plugin to the extensions in chrome by finding a solution on the following link
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7569

However after adding the Google chrome plugin to the extension it is giving me the following error :[image]

Comment: Java is not JavaScript for future reference, fixed your tags :)

Comment: @AlexColeman are you sure it's Javascript? The Google Web Toolkit, which he references in his question, and the error look Java-ish to me. Plus, he's not developing an extension, but a plugin (at least as far as I can tell).

Comment: @JimmySawczuk He tagged JavaScript and Java, and it's web related, so I'm assuming he meant JavaScript; may be wrong though

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583558/gwt-plugin-for-chrome/10598959#10598959

Comment: @AlexColeman GWT is toolkit to write and maintain an application in mostly-Java, but have it compile and run in JavaScript - web related, yes, JavaScript enters the picture eventually, but all/most development happens in Java.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Alright, my mistake, apologies :)

Comment: @Guys  I have tried all solutions on the link you provided beforehand however, though it shows the google web toolkit to have installed in the extensions. It is still giving the second error (second image) which I have shown in my question. When I click on Ok on this message box the page refreshes and hangs up. This error proves that google chrome is not able to support Google web toolkit plugin though it has been installed.What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: What project did you run that gives this error?

Comment: @texasbruce I am running my own self developed project which runs absolutely fine on Firefox however, on google chrome comes up with this error.

Answer (score 6):

There are currently some issues with Google Chrome and the GWT DevMode plugin - and the GWT team is working on it. It's not easy to always catch up with the latest releases of all browsers. And I wouldn't want them spending all their resources on doing that.

As a GWT app developer, I know it's painful when the plugin stops working, because browser releases are frequent, and updates occur automatically nowadays.

However, I would recommend GWT app developers to switch the strategy a bit: Ask yourself, if you really need to test with the *very latest* version of a browser *in dev mode*, as you can

- test with the very latest version of a browser in production mode (or maybe super dev mode)
- develop using a slightly older version of a browser in dev mode.

It's easy to install e.g. a slightly outdated Chromium build, side by side to Chrome. This doesn't mean that plugin issues shouldn't be fixed quickly, but it gives the GWT team at least a few weeks after a browser release - without real drawbacks for GWT app developers.

Maybe this should be the official recommendation for working with DevMode, i.e. instead of failing to install, the plugin should offer a description how to get it installed in another version of the browser (it already does that for Safari/Mac!)

Comment: Ok I will go with your solution Chris. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your last issue is http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5778

On the http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7569 side, the plugin has yet to be recompiled for Windows, but should otherwise be fixed and deployable to the Chrome Web Store.