# Chrome: Could not load GWT DevMode Plugin

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

My GWT plugin is installed and enabled

[image]

When my application loads however, i get

[image]

What is the problem here? What do you recommend i try to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583558/gwt-plugin-for-chrome/10598959#10598959 ?

Comment: Ah, you are on Mac, then this won't be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome 22 for Mac dropped support for long-deprecated plugin models, which the GWT plugin still uses; there's nothing you can do to make that version of the plugin load. The plugin source has [already been updated](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=11310) to be compatible with current version of Chrome, there just needs to be a new release of the plugin including that change.

Comment: I ended up installing FF15 to take care of this. Thanks smorgan! Hopefully google's best are on the case and we'll see the fix soon